# How to capture everything to end of last line with DOTALL in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
Acid Exposure (pH)      Total
            Total   Normal

        Clearance pH  :  Channel 7
        Number of Acid Episodes 26  
        Time    31.5 min    
        Percent Time    7.4%    
        Mean Acid Clearance Time    73 sec  
        Longest Episode 7.1 min

        Gastric pH  :  Channel 8
        Time pH<4.0 425.9 min



    Bolus Exposure (Impedance)      Total
            Total   Normal

        Acid Time   22.0 min    
        Acid Percent Time   5.2%    
        Nonacid Time    6.1 min 
        Nonacid Percent Time    1.4%    
        All Reflux Time 28.2 min    
        All Reflux Percent Time 6.6%    
        Median Bolus Clearance Time 16 sec  
        Longest Episode 7.8 min
```

I want to capture everything from `Acid Exposure` to `Time pH<` including everything on the line of `Time pH<` so that I end up with:

```
Acid Exposure (pH)      Total
            Total   Normal

        Clearance pH  :  Channel 7
        Number of Acid Episodes 26  
        Time    31.5 min    
        Percent Time    7.4%    
        Mean Acid Clearance Time    73 sec  
        Longest Episode 7.1 min

        Gastric pH  :  Channel 8
        Time pH<4.0 425.9 min
```

The way I have tried to capture this is with:

```
Pattern my_pattern = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure.*?Time pH.*?$",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but I have had no luck. I also tried adding `Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.MULTILINE` but also no luck

Comment: What method are you using, `find()` or `matches()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Pattern my_pattern = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure.*?Time pH<[^\\n]*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

`[^\n]*` after `Time pH<` will match until end of line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB7dG3/1)

Comment: How could I do this to the second Time pH< ?

Comment: Your example has only one `Time pH<`. In general you can do `while(matcher.find() {...}` and print all the matches.

Comment: I know. I was just trying to sneak in a question extension. I was really asking if there were two Time pH< in the original text, how could I match from the beginning to the second one rather than just stop at the first

Comment: Can there be 3rd `Time pH<` as well? Do you want to match until last `Time pH<` is matched?

Comment: Just until the second one. Yes there can be a third

Comment: You can use [`Acid Exposure(?:.*?Time pH<[^\n]*){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/rB7dG3/2) but please avoid changing problem via comments.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using the dot-all modifier in a cluster surrounding `.*?`
So, you don't need to use the *global* dot-all modifier.

`Acid Exposure(?s:.*?)Time pH.*`

And,  for some strange reason `(?s:.*?)` is faster than `[\S\s]*?` in engines.

Comment: `(?s:)` is called an inline modifier, and `.` is surely faster than `[\s\S]` construct, since the `.` is a "native" match-all construct, and `[\s\S]` is a more complex, "user-defined" class that should be compiled first.